# Строка как условие в if (python)

Tags: python

```
if var==(str("yes")) или `if var = "yes"`
```

нужно что-то примерно такое. В итоге хочу, чтобы `if` выполняла заданное, если переменная равна определенной строке. возможно ли?

Comment: а в чем проблема у вас? Само сравнение(1вариант) у вас правильно? Что конкретно вас смещает?

Comment: Совсем необязательно конвертировать строку в строку. Ведь она уже и так строка.

Answer (score 3):

```
my_var = "yes"
if my_var == "yes":
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if input("print yes or no\n").lower() == "yes":
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var = 'Hello!'
if var == 'Hello!':
    print(var)
else:
    print('Bye bye!')
```